# Shared Cocoapods between app projects and shared library

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I've got an Xcode 9 workspace with two app projects (`App1` and `App2`), and a framework project (`Lib1`) which holds common code that is shared between the two apps.

Now, I'm using CocoaPods to manage dependencies that are shared by all three projects.

```
App1      App2
^ ^       ^ ^ ^
| |_______| | |
|     |     | Pod2
|    Lib1   |
|     ^     |
|_____|_____|
|
Pod1
```

I've tried all sorts of things but I cannot seem to configure the Podfile correctly!

Here is what I've got currently:

```
platform :ios, '11.0'
workspace 'amazing.xcworkspace'
use_frameworks!

target 'Lib1' do
    project 'Lib1/Lib1'
    pod 'Pod1'
    target 'Lib1Tests' do
        inherit! :search_paths
        # Pods for testing
    end

    # App1
    target 'App1' do
        project 'App1/App1'
        inherit! :search_paths
        target 'App1Tests' do
            inherit! :search_paths
            # Pods for testing
        end
    end

    # App2
    target 'App2' do
        project 'App2/App2'
        pod 'Pod2'
        inherit! :search_paths
        target 'App2Tests' do
            inherit! :search_paths
            # Pods for testing
        end
    end
end
```

I get errors at runtime relating to multiple instances of a framework being on the search path, or `dyld` errors because library images cannot be found...

**What is the correct way to set up the Podfile for this scenario??**